# DAG to only run specific tasks

Tags: airflow

I have `dag` which contains `4 tasks` but i only want 1 of them to run. How can i do this.

**At the beggining i had:**

```
create_pet_table >> populate_pet_table >> get_all_pets >> get_birth_date
```

**i removed 3 of them and at the end i got:**

```
get_all_pets
```

Nevertheless when i look at the log **it looks like all 4 were executed:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as the operators objects are there, the tasks will be executed. Comment or remove the code of the operators you don't want to execute